# Error handling and conditional chaining of Actix actors

Tags: rust, rust-actix, actix-web

This is my first attempt at writing a small webservice with rust, using actix-web.

The code below is a request handler that is intended to do three things, insert an entry in the database, send an email if that db call was successful, and then return a json payload as the response.

`data.dal` (database call) and `data.email_service` are references to Actors.

The issue: is I am unable to capture the error returned by `data.dal`. Any attempt to reconfigure the below code seems to give me an error stating the compiler wasn't able to find a conversion from Actix Mailbox to [Type].

Is there an alternate/better way to rewrite this? Basically when the request is issued, I'd like to be able to call Actor A. And if the result from A is Ok then call Actor B. If the results from both are okay return a JSON payload. If either A or B return an error (can have different error types), return an custom error message.

```rust
pub fn register_email(
    invitation: Json<EmailInvitationInput>,
    data: web::Data<AppState>,
) -> impl Future<Item=HttpResponse, Error=Error> {
    let m = dal::queries::CreateEmailInvitation { email: invitation.email.clone() };
    data.dal.send(m)
        .from_err()
        .and_then(move |res| {
            let invite = res.unwrap();
            let email_input = email::SendLoginLink {
                from: "from_email".to_string(),
                to: "to_email".to_string(),
            };
            data.email_service.send(email_input)
                .from_err()
                .and_then(move |res| match res {
                    Ok(_) => {
                        Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(EmailInvitationOutput { expires_at: invite.expires_at }))
                    }
                    Err(err) => {
                        debug!("{:#?}", err);
                        Ok(ServiceError::InternalServerError.error_response())
                    }
                })
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to have an `Error` type that agglomerates all different errors, the coercion to this type can be achieved implicitly by declaring the appropriate `From` implementations and what you are doing `from_err()` but here I am being explicit:

I haven't tested this code snippet but this is how I have done it in projects I'm working on that use Actix:

```rust
data.dal.send(m)
    .map_err(Error::Mailbox)
    .and_then(|res| res.map_err(Error::Service))
    .and_then(move |invite| {
        let email_input = email::SendLoginLink {
            from: "from_email".to_string(),
            to: "to_email".to_string(),
        };
        data.email_service.send(email_input)
            .map_err(Error::Mailbox)
            .and_then(|res| res.map_err(Error::Service))
            .and_then(move |res| HttpResponse::Ok().json(EmailInvitationOutput { expires_at: invite.expires_at }))
    })
    .or_else(|err| {
        debug!("{:#?}", err);
        ServiceError::InternalServerError.error_response()
    })
```

(I'm assuming `ServiceError` implements `IntoFuture` just like `HttpResponse` does)